# How do I cron schedule a playlist shortcut on my desktop

Tags: bash, cron, raspberry-pi-desktop

How do I trigger a shortcut "My_Favourites.xspf" that lives on my desktop.

I would like to start playing this playlist of music in the morning to wake me up.

Just to explain better: When I double click the shortcut, that opens VLC Media player and plays the songs in that list.
I would like the songs to start play without me touching anything.

Directly after that, I want to open in "full screen" a list of saved bookmarks. (They all are in one folder) 
If I right-click on that folder, all webpages open at once.

How do I autostart these from cron?

(Would I need a bash script? How does that script look?)

Any help will be appreciated VERY much.

Comment: Please do a bit of research first: Learn how to start the "VLC media player" from the command line. Once you've done that, edit your question to include the command line entry to start the VLC app.

Comment: This question does not belong to Raspberry Pi. I cannot find any word about Raspberry Pi in it. It's a general GUI programming question. You should better ask on one of your partent sites.